# Symbian S60 Email View Component

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, nokia, s60

Does anyone know what component is used to view HTML emails in the default symbian mail app. Specifically those using the Symbian3 S60 - J2ME Midlet?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a component for viewing HTML.

In **Symbian C++** applications you can use [Browser Control](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Browser_Control_API)

In **Qt** applications you can use [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebview.html)

In **MIDLets** you can use the e[SWT Browser Control](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000974_-_Using_eSWT_Browser_in_Java_ME) which is a wrapper around the Symbian Browser Control